# What's **if (no errors)**? 

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I am trying to implement transactions to Kohana but it seems to be not so easy as in Spring/Java.

So far I found this code to try but I don't know how to replace the part (no errors)

```
DB::query('START TRANSACTION');
// sql queries with query builder..

if (no errors)
    DB::query('COMMIT');
else
    DB::query('ROLLBACK');
```

How do I make the if clause?

Comment: Looks like pseudo-code to me. I'm not familiar with Kohana, so I don't know the specific function to check for MySQL errors, but that's where you should check to see if there was a MySQL error in the 'START TRANSACTION' query, methinks. Perhaps something like `$result = DB::query('START TRANSACTION'); if ($result)`

Comment: How are errors detected in the first place? Are Exceptions been `throw`ed? does it return false on fail? Will it throw a `trigger_error()`?

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand. With Kohana, this does not seem to be well supported or exist.

Answer (score 2):

Normally transactions are handled as such:

```
DB::query('START TRANSACTION');
try {
    //do something
    DB::query('COMMIT');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::query('ROLLBACK');
}
```

What this means is if everything succeeds within the `try` block, great.  If any part of it fails then it won't reach the `commit` and will jump to the `catch` block, which contains the `rollback`.  You can add more error handling within the `catch` if you wish, even throw a new exception of your own or throw the same exception you caught.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I have to do NULL, 'start transaction' otherwise Kohana gives an error. Secondly, Kohana executes all the queries individually instead of processing them as a part of the transaction. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap everything in a try/catch block:

```
DB::query('START TRANSACTION');
try {
    // sql queries with query builder..

    DB::query('COMMIT');
} catch (Database_Exception $e) {
    DB::query('ROLLBACK');
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. I have to do NULL, 'start transaction' otherwise Kohana gives an error. Secondly, Kohana executes all the queries individually instead of processing them as a part of the transaction. What might be the issue?

Comment: Transactions are not done on the Kohana side, but in the database. It is perfectly kay for Kohana to execute the queries individually, as they will be part of one transaction on the DB server. Or do you have any indication that the database does not really start a transaction?

Comment: What would be a good way to fail a part of the transaction to test? I am executing two queries. With one of them, if I supply a wrong column name (on purpose) I see that even though I get the rollback error, first part is executed. Perhaps I should go back to native SQL when using Kohana, instead of query builders?

Comment: Are you saying that the `ROLLBACK` command has no effect? If that is the case, please check if your database is properly configured to support transactions.

Answer (score 0):

DB errors are converted to exceptions:

```
DB::query('START TRANSACTION');
try {
     // sql queries with query builder..
     DB::query('COMMIT');
}
catch($e)
{
    $this->template->body = new View('db_error');
    $this->template->body->error = 'An error occurred ...';
    DB::query('ROLLBACK');
}
```

Comment: link about it: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/1806/handling-sql-errors-and-other-non-critical-errors/p1

Comment: Hello, first of all, I have to do NULL, 'start transaction' otherwise Kohana gives an error. Secondly, Kohana executes all the queries individually instead of processing them as a part of the transaction. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kohana 3:

```
$db = Database::instance();
$db->begin();
try
{
    // Do your queries here
    $db->commit();
}
catch (Database_Exception $e)
{
    $db->rollback();
}
```